# Disabling TLS 1.0/ on Wordpress

Tags: tls, wordpress

I run a Wordpress website on a OVH plan, so I don't have direct control over the server. I want to disable TLS V1.0 since it has known security vulnerabilities.

Most guides I have found on this have been to change settings on Apache/Nginx, but I don't have that ability. Is there any way to do this through .htaccess or plugins?

The certificate is provided by Lets Encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to contact your hosting provider. It's possible that they'll upgrade it for you but on the other hand they may ask you to "upgrade" to a newer hosting plan.

AFAIK there's no way to change this via `.htaccess` as it deals with a higher level of the software stack (i.e. resource permissions and routing). The same is likely true of plugins; they shouldn't have privileges to alter the server configuration beyond what you would have.